# Unicode "uprightdown" and "northeastsoutheast" arrows

Tags: math-mode, symbols, luatex, arrows, unicode

Similar to the `\leftrightarrow commands`, I'd like to create two new commands that are usable in mathmode, specifically as index. The resulting symbol should be of the same size as a single arrow. I suspect this can be done with some stacking and perhaps masking, but I couldn't get past the starting point.

a) A combination of the north-east arrow ↗ `^^^^2197` and the south-east arrow ↘ `^^^^2198`. I tried using

```
\stackrel{^^^^2197}{^^^^2198}
```

as a starting point, but I don't see any result, while using the arrows normally works (without stackrel). The result should look like a `K` (not an X), without the vertical bar, with arrows pointing north-east and south-east.

b) Basically a `T`, rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise, with arrows pointing up (↑ `^^^^2191`), right (→ `^^^^2192`) and down (↓ `^^^^2193`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@Karrows}[1]{%
    \clipbox{{.5\width} -1 0 -1}{%
        \ooalign{$#1\nearrow$\cr$#1\searrow$}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*{\Karrows}{%
    \mathpalette\@Karrows{}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\Tarrows}{%
    \updownarrow%
    \mathchoice%
        {\mkern-5.5mu}%
        {\mkern-5.5mu}%
        {\mkern-6mu}%
        {\mkern-6mu}%
    \rightarrow%
}
\begin{document}
\(
    \displaystyle\Karrows
    \textstyle\Karrows
    \scriptstyle\Karrows
    \scriptscriptstyle\Karrows
\)

\(
    \displaystyle\Tarrows
    \textstyle\Tarrows
    \scriptstyle\Tarrows
    \scriptscriptstyle\Tarrows
\)
\end{document}
```